# CSS formatting parent element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to format the .card-body parent element if it contains an element of the .adrotate_widget class. I do this with the following JavaScript:

```
  <script> 
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('div:has(.adrotate_widgets)').css('padding', '0'); 
     }); 
  </script>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    <aside id="adrotate_widgets-3" class="widget adrotate_widgets"></aside>
</div>
```

But unfortunately, I get the error message

> "TypeError: $ is not a function“

and the parent element is not changed.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Bernward

Comment: Did you include [jQuery library](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js) like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the direct parent, you can do this with `.parent()`.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".adrotate_widgets").parent().css('padding', '0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <aside id="adrotate_widgets-3" class="widget adrotate_widgets"></aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use `:parent` selector.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".adrotate_widgets:parent").css('padding', '0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <aside id="adrotate_widgets-3" class="widget adrotate_widgets"></aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/parent/

**Update**

This should work with jQuery v1.12.4 just fine. You may encounter Namespacing issues, so look out for that.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".adrotate_widgets:parent").css('padding', '0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <aside id="adrotate_widgets-3" class="widget adrotate_widgets"></aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. The used WordPress theme loads the following jQuery library:
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://gruenes-muensterland.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script>
But apparently it doesn't work with that, because with version 3.3.1 it works. Can I adjust the JavaScript accordingly? I do not want to change the theme and cause other problems.

Here you can go to the webpage: 
https://gruenes-muensterland.de/anbieter/germany/nordrhein-westfalen/kreis-steinfurt/hoefe-maerkte/demeter-gaertnerei-entrup/

Thanks!
Bernward

Comment: @conImago if you're using WP, you might have some NameSpacing issues. It just means you may have to use `jQuery()` versus `$()`. I added an update that might help explain. The general code would be the same.

Comment: @Tisty: Yeah, that's the solution. Thank you. Now it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `Jquery library` like below.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('div:has(.adrotate_widgets)').css('padding', '0');
       console.log($(".card-body").css("padding")) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    123
    <aside id="adrotate_widgets-3" class="widget adrotate_widgets"></aside>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @conImago

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have successfully included the jquery library in your project like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

something like the following would work:

```
$(function() {
  $(".adrotate_widgets").closest('.card-body').css('padding', '0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using addClass method.

```
$('div:has(.adrotate_widgets)').addClass('zeroPadding');
```

```
<style type="text/css">
.zeroPadding { padding:0; background-color: yellow;}
</style>
```